# Getting the number of occurances in a range R

Tags: r, count, range

I looked up all possible questions&answers about how to find a number of counts in a column,when the start time of a variable 2 (`V2`) and 3 (`V3`) falls within the range of + 25 sec and - 25 sec from the start time of variable 1 (`V1`).

E.g.

```
var start

V1  268.523
V1  296.986
V1  306.701
V1  311.586
V1  342.755
V1  358.539
V2  337.968
V2  339.808
V2  340.948
V2  357.278
V2  358.718
V3  297.936
V3  300.156
V3  307.734
V3  311.378
V3  339.046
```

E.g. If 1st (`V1`) starts at 268.525 sec, the range of +25sec and - 25sec is from 293.523 until 243.523. If the start of `V2` and `V3` fits in this "time window" it should be counted as 1.

I would appreciate, if someone could give me a hint how to get the information, I from the data set.

Comment: What are Var1 , Var2, Var3?  Is it the same as V1, V2, V3?  Can you also show the expected output

Comment: But what happens if some of the values in `V2` or `V3` overlap with several values in `V1` like in your example? What is the expected output here?

Comment: @ David: this is what I was also thinking of.The thing is, I want to only have the number of variables that fall withing this range. If the "time window" of first `V1` + 25 sec overlaps with the second `V1` than, the range of start of `V1` - 25 sec shouldn't be calculated because it was already calculated with `V1`. Does my explanation make sens to you?

Comment: See my edit. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: In principal, it's perfect there is only one small but. I edited my question, so that you can see what is my problem with "overlaps". Is there a possibility of solving this with your code?

Comment: Can you show desired output please? I'm inclining to close this question as "unclear" as you keep editing it without providing your actual desired output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: FYI...I wasn't sure how my desired output can look like therefore I kept it open for eventual feedback. Your solution is pretty much what I hoped to get from a table. Still, I have 2 questions. Please see them below, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you want something as the following. I've separated your data into two data sets. `df1` where `var == "V1"` and `df2` where `var != "V1"`. Then I've set +-25 ranges within `df1` to match against and added a row index in order to know which row was matched against `df2` afterwards. Then I've keyed both data set by matching column and ran `foverlaps` in order to find overlap ranges. Finally, you can aggregate by both the `index` and the matched variable names and the `dcast` the data and join afterwards

You will probably need the development version on GH (v 1.9.5+), see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.5+
df1 <- setDT(df)[var == "V1"]
df2 <- df[var != "V1"]

df1[, `:=`(from = start - 25L, to = start + 25L, indx = .I)]
setkey(df1, from, to)

df2[, end := start]
setkey(df2, start, end)

res <- foverlaps(df2, df1)[, .(start = toString(i.start), .N), by = .(indx, i.var)]
res <- dcast(res, indx ~ i.var, value.var = c("N", "start"))

setkey(df1, indx)
setkey(res, indx)[df1]

#    indx N_V2 N_V3                                    start_V2                           start_V3 var   start    from      to
# 1:    1   NA   NA                                          NA                                 NA  V1 268.523 243.523 293.523
# 2:    2   NA    4                                          NA 297.936, 300.156, 307.734, 311.378  V1 296.986 271.986 321.986
# 3:    3   NA    4                                          NA 297.936, 300.156, 307.734, 311.378  V1 306.701 281.701 331.701
# 4:    4   NA    4                                          NA 297.936, 300.156, 307.734, 311.378  V1 311.586 286.586 336.586
# 5:    5    5    1 337.968, 339.808, 340.948, 357.278, 358.718                            339.046  V1 342.755 317.755 367.755
# 6:    6    5    1 337.968, 339.808, 340.948, 357.278, 358.718                            339.046  V1 358.539 333.539 383.539
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("V1", "V2", "V3"
), class = "factor"), start = c(268.523, 296.986, 306.701, 311.586, 
342.755, 358.539, 337.968, 339.808, 340.948, 357.278, 358.718, 
297.936, 300.156, 307.734, 311.378, 339.046)), .Names = c("var", 
"start"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: I applied your code (with `dcast`) to my data. Everything works until `dcast`. I get the error, the function cannot be found. I tried to install `reshape2` package but it doesn't help. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The table you suggested is perfect, would it be possible to attach 2 additional columns with the information when `V2` and `V3` started?Thank you as always!

Comment: Try using `dcast.data.table` instead of just `dcast`. I'm just using a newer `data.table` version than you. Not sure what you mean by `*when V2 and V3 started*`. You have several matches per row so you will have several values for starts and ends. Can you show desired output combined with the table you already got?

Comment: The `dcast.data.table` works perfectly. As for the question `*when V2 and V3 started*`, I simply wanna know, if I can have `start` values of `V2` and `V3` next to the columns with frequencies. I'll extend your table above, if it's okay, so that you can see the output.

Comment: It's not the prettiest output but if several `V2` and `V3` variable fall in the range `from` - `to`, it will look like that. Let me know, if you understand now what am I asking for. Many thanks.

Comment: See my edit. I think you will need the development version in order to run this. Try `install.packages("devtools");library(devtools);install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE);library(data.table)` in a fresh R sessions and then run my code

Comment: I have installed the development version on Mac because on Win it didn't work. The table is exactly what I wanted, many thanks for that. I have two comments still: 1. After running the code, my header duplicated and is also visible at the end of the table. Why? 2. After running the code, I received a warning message: `In setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) :
  Already keyed by this key but had invalid row order, key rebuilt. If you didn't go under the hood please let datatable-help know so the root cause can be fixed.` Should I do something with it?

Comment: I've edited the post to have only the desired code. Try it with the provided data set too.

Comment: Running `install.packages("devtools")` and `library(devtools)` is okay. I downloaded `Rtools32.` for Windows. And after pressing `install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)` I get a new warning message `Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached`. On Mac, the stuff works without any problems.